# Query Graph API /feed with like info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

How to query Graph API `page-id/feed` so it returns information about if every returned post is liked by access token owner?

One query is requirement.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please do some research (google, facebook docs, tutorials, ...) and improve your question with more details.

Comment: It's not always possible to include every information needed to formulate the answer in question. I'll call you when i'll need to know what color blue flower is, but now please go "help" someone else.

Comment: it is ALWAYS possible to include what you have tried so far ;)

Comment: anyway, i will answer

Comment: btw, may i ask what for you need this exactly?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single API call for this, you would need to go through every like in the result to check if the User ID is in there.

Keep in mind that you would need to use paging in order to get all likes though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

...So that would be a LOT of calls, unfortunately. Depending on the number of likes.